# HTTPS support on Windows Phone 8 HttpClient

Tags: https, windows-phone-8, httpclient, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I am trying to use Nuget Http client library:

```
 HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    request.Headers.Add("UserAgent", "Windows 8 app client");

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
      return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    else
     throw new Exception("Error connecting to " + url +" ! Status: " + response.StatusCode);
```

When I make a https request to a site that has self-signed certificate, I get 404 error. How do I set a flag to allow invalid SSL certificate in the client?

Comment: What happens if you install the certificate locally?  In that use of an invalid certificate would mean that the content isn't encrypted why use https in this case anyway?

Comment: ssk have you solved this problem?

Comment: @GeorgeNikolaides The only way that I found to solve the problem is add a valid root certificate to the server.

Comment: Well yes - there is another way for debug purposes by using fiddler. Its sad that android & iOS are able to accept an unverified certificate and WP cant yet. Anyway..Thank you!!

Comment: For normal .NET apps I have used this to ignore SSL cert errors:           System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true; But that is not supported on WP...